# Postgres: SQL Error [42846]: ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to date

Tags: postgresql

I am having a Postgres database,
And I am trying to query a table for getting the latest transaction made by each user, before a particular unix time
**But I am getting the following error -**

```
SQL Error [42846]: ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to date
  Position: 187
```

**Following is my query -**

```
SELECT 
    T2.user_id,
    T2.transaction_id AS latest_transaction_id,
    T2.new_balance AS balance,
    T2.created_date AS last_transaction_timestamp,
    to_char(T2.created_date :: date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') AS last_transaction_date,
    to_date(to_char(now() :: date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd') AS snapshot_date,
    to_char(now() :: date, 'yyyy') AS year
FROM
    (SELECT 
        user_id, MAX(transaction_id) maxTransID
    FROM
        public.transaction
    WHERE
        created_date < 1564444799
    GROUP BY user_id) Tmp
        JOIN
    public.transaction T2 ON Tmp.MaxTransID = T2.Transaction_ID;
```

**Following is my table structure -**
[image]

**Following is the table DDL -**

```
CREATE TABLE public.transaction (
    transaction_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    user_id int8 NULL,
    created_date int8 NULL,
    debit_amount numeric(15,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
    credit_amount numeric(15,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
    previous_balance numeric(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    new_balance numeric(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    reference_id varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    activity_type bpchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
    activity_title varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    activity_desc text NOT NULL,
    activity_desc_show int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'::smallint,
    added_by varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    added_by_role varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    CONSTRAINT transaction_pkey PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);
CREATE INDEX index_activity_type ON public.transaction USING btree (activity_type);
CREATE INDEX index_created_date ON public.transaction USING btree (created_date);
CREATE INDEX index_reference_id ON public.transaction USING btree (reference_id);
CREATE INDEX index_user_id ON public.transaction USING btree (user_id);
```

What am I doing wrong? 
What do I change?

Comment: Why would you define a column named `created_date` as `int`? That should be a `date` (and unrelated: you should not use the `bpchar` or `char` type at all)

Comment: I’m using bigint for created_date as I want to store a UTC unix 10 digit timestamp in the column

Comment: A `timestamp` is a much better choice for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually the data is being migrated from MySql, and the field created_date was to be a timestamp in MySQL but we decided to use BIGINT, as MySQL timestamp has life until 2038. So we just carried on with BIGINT in Postgres as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name was able to resolve the query as you suggested, ->  to_timestamp(T2.created_date) AS last_transaction_timestamp,

Comment: A `timestamp` in Postgres does not have the stupid limitations as MySQL's type